# Windows Phone Cloud Application ASPProviders returns could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient with Azure SDK 1.7

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

After updating azure sdk to 1.7, my windows phone toolkit for azure application stop working now in visual studio and shows an exception. My windows phone 7 application is best on ASPProviders and when it runs in emulator, page returns error.

Looking into exception I see below:
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Any idea on how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that Windows Phone 7.1 toolkit is based on Windows Azure SDK 1.6 and when you have installed Windows Azure SDK 1.7, the updated version of Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.dll is causing this problem.

To fix this problem you can setup a binding redirect to the newer version of Windows Azure Storage Client DLL as below in your application:

```
<dependentAssembly>
 <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
 <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.7.0.0" newVersion="1.7.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

This should fix your problem.